# Error Passing Const as this

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

im working on a project for school and have this error but i cannot figure out out to fix it:

error: passing ‘const xArray’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘size_t xArray::PushBack(int)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  a.PushBack(temp);

Here is the function that the error comes from:

```
    istream& operator>>(istream& in, const xArray& a)
    {
          int temp;
          in >> temp;
          a.PushBack(temp);

          return in;
    }
```

Here is my code for PushBack:

```
    size_t xArray::PushBack(int c)
    {

            if(len == arraySize)
            {
                     int* temp = new int[arraySize* 2];
                     size_t i;
                     for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                     {
                            temp[i] = data[i];
                     }
                     delete [] data;
                     data = temp;
                     data[len+1] = c;
                     len = len + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                  data[len + 1] = c;
                  len = len + 1;
            }
    }
```

Any help on how to fix or an explanation of this error would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's `const`, therefore you can't modify it in any way, including by pushing stuff onto it.

Comment: It's exactly what the compiler says. You call a non const member function on a const object. In generally the istream `>>` operator changes the second element and should be passed by reference but not as a const reference.

Answer (score 1):

For `istream& operator>>(istream& in, const xArray& a)`, `a` is declared as const, and calling `PushBack()` on it will fail because `xArray::PushBack()` is a non-const member function.

You might change the parameter type of `a` to non-const reference, such as

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, xArray& a)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Cant believe i didn't notice that! thanks everything works fine!

Comment: @programmer0980 Actually you could get the hint from the error message, it says "passing ‘const xArray’ as ‘this’..."